# dual of a smooth hypersurface is still a hypersurface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^{n}$ of degree $\geq 2$ and denote by $\check{\mathbb{P}}^{n}$ the dual projective space. I am trying to show that the image of $X$ under the Gauss map :
\begin{alignat*}{5}
    \gamma : \: & X \: & \rightarrow \: & \check{\mathbb{P}}^{n}  \: & \\
    \: & P \: & \mapsto  \: & [\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_0}(P), \: &  \cdots, \frac{\partial F}{\partial x_n}(P)]
   \end{alignat*}
is still a projective hypersurface (non necessarily smooth). It seems that my reasoning is wrong but I don't understand why, neither how to solve the problem if my solution is indeed not correct. A hint I received is to show that the fibers are zero-dimensional, I think that then the result will be direct since for any surjective morphism of quasi-projective varieties $\phi : X \rightarrow Y$, given $y \in Y$ we know that $\dim(\phi^{-1}(y)) = \dim(X)- \dim(Y)$.

So I only have to show that the fibers are zero dimensional. A "point" on $\gamma(X)$ is a tangent space $T$ to $X$ at a given point $P\in X$. So assume that there is a fibre of strictly positive dimension. Then it means that $\gamma$ would be constant on a curve $C$ contained in $X$. But then this means that the tangent space to each point of the curve is the same. Intuitively I would say that this will contradict the smoothness of $X$ but I don't succeed in showing it properly.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the map is not finite. Then $\gamma$ is constant on a complete curve $C\subset X$. The partials $\partial_i F$ restricted to $C$ are then scalar multiples of each other, so they have a common zero. But that is absurd.

Note that this works because $d\ge 2$ means the partials are non-constant polynomials. When $d=1$, the image of the Gauss map is a point, and the partials are all constant.

Jake Levinson mentioned the following details in the comments.

> [F]or morphisms between projective varieties (such as the Gauss map),
>   "finite" is equivalent to "finite fibers", so "not finite" means some
>   fiber is positive-dimensional, hence contains a curve. The curve is
>   complete because it is a closed subscheme of a projective variety (and
>   projective varieties are complete).

Comment: Where are you using $d\geq 2$?

Comment: @JakeLevinson If $d=1$, the map is to a point, because the hypersurface is a hyperplane.

Comment: Indeed, and that is not absurd...

Comment: @JakeLevinson Then I think I don't understand your question. The problem asks about $d\ge 2$, so the partials are non-constant polynomials.

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly ! Just to be sure : what does it mean for a map to not be finite ? Is it equivalent to say that the fibres are 0-dimensional ? Why is the curve complete then ? (by complete do you mean that the image of $C \times Y \rightarrow Y$ is closed in $Y$ for any quasi-projective variety $Y$ ?)

Comment: @Patrick: Ah, that's the missing thing (the partials are non-constant). The point was, nowhere in your answer was the condition $d \geq 2$ evidently used. As such, I wasn't sure what would go wrong in attempting to apply your answer to the case $d = 1$ (where something would have to break).

Comment: @Marianne: for morphisms between projective varieties (such as the Gauss map), "finite" is equivalent to "finite fibers", so "not finite" means some fiber is positive-dimensional, hence contains a curve. The curve is complete because it is a closed subscheme of a projective variety (and projective varieties are complete).

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I still have some troubles: first of all the way I conclude as soon as I succeed in showing that my fibers are zero-dimensional: I use the fact that the restriction $X \rightarrow im(\gamma)$ is still a morphism of varieties since $X$ is projective so its image is closed in $\mathbb{P}^{1}$. But if I can use the result mentioned above (namely "for any surjective morphism of quasi-projective varieties $ϕ:X\rightarrow Y$, $\dim(\phi^{-1})(y))=\dim(X)−\dim(Y)$" for all $ y\in Y$ but this would imply that $\dim(X)= \dim(\gamma(Y)$ in this case which seems at least curious,

Comment: I just realized that in my pevious answer $\dim(\gamma(Y))$ should be $\dim(\gamma(X))$, I didn't suceed to edit the comment... Another point: I don't understand why the partial derivatives are scalar multiple to each other when restricted to the curve. I know that they belong to the same hyperplane but I don't see how it would imply the claim.

Comment: @Marianne For the first question: Isn't $\operatorname{dim}(X)=\operatorname{dim}(\gamma(X))$ exactly what you want? Both varieties live in projective spaces of the same dimension, so if their dimensions are equal and $X$ is a hypersurface, then $\gamma(X)$ is.

Comment: @Marianne For the second: If $\gamma$ is constant on $C$, then in particular $\partial_0 F/\partial_1 F$ is constant on $C$ (if $\partial_1 F$ doesn't vanish, but deal with this case separately.) So $\partial_0 F$ is always a scalar multiple of $\partial_1 F$. Then continue in this way...

Comment: Thanks for these answers! I was really confused indeed! Everything is clear now, thanks a lot!