# Dimension of the fiber of a projective variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

When looking at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1515239/dual-of-a-smooth-hypersurface-is-still-a-hypersurface/1515245) I found the theorem

Given a surjective map of quasi-projective varieties $\phi:X\rightarrow Y$ and $y\in Y$, we have that dim$(\phi^{-1}(y))=$dim$(X)$-dim$(Y)$.

First I was trying to proof this but I couldn't seem to find a start. Then I tried to look it up online but no author bothered to proof the result.

Can one provide me with a hint how to start the proof, with a reference for the proof or even with the complete proof?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't give you a hint because the result is false !

For a counterexample take $Y=\mathbb P^2$ and blow-up some point $O\in Y$.
You will obtain a blown-up variety $X$ and a morphism $\phi:X\to Y$.
The fiber $\phi^{-1}(O)$ of isomorphic to  $\mathbb P^1$ so that $$\operatorname {dim}(\phi^{-1}(O))=\operatorname {dim}(\mathbb P^1)=1\gt \operatorname {dim}(X)-\operatorname {dim}(Y)=2-2=0$$

The equality you are after is however generically true: there is an open non-empty subset $U\subset Y$ such that for every  $y\in U$ one has indeed: dim$(\phi^{-1}(y))=$dim$(X)$-dim$(Y)$.
The (non-trivial) proof can be found in [Shafarevich](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Ldqod_Ixc_IC&redir_esc=y), page 76.

Comment: thank you very much! this counter example was very enlightning!